# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError (“\xFF” from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8) error for rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am having this error while uploading image. I tried to add activesupport-json_encoder gem in Gemfile as mentioned in https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1404, but activesupport-json_encoder does not work with rails 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough data, but I guess I had a similar issue before, so try to use `utf8mb4` for encoding in your `database.yml` file and tell me if that fixes it for you

Comment: still the same error 
it look like thin in my  .yml file :
`code`development:
  <<: *default
  encoding: utf8mb4
  database: myDB
`code`